# WSO2 ESB setting soap envelope from property

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have to set the soap envolope from a OM property populated with xml content. I use the enrich mediator to do this with the following code:

```
 <log>
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="envelope" expression="$ctx:mensaje" />
</log>
<enrich>
  <source xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" clone="false" type="property" property="mensaje" />
  <target action="replace" type="envelope" xpath="" property="" />
</enrich>
```

The log instruction shows a correct soap envelope but the system log stops with

```
08:12:26,997 [-] [HttpServerWorker-8] INFO Start : Enrich mediator
```

and I get this soap fault:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Index: 0, Size: 0</faultstring>
     <detail/>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to get property from message context..Use like this in your source configuration..

get-property('mensaje')